# Access date_select in rails model before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, date

Rails 3.2.8

In the model, I'm unable to access the `start_date` gathered in the form.

```
# form
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :start_date %><br />
  <%= f.date_select :start_date %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :total_months %><br />
  <%= f.number_field :total_months %>
</div>


# model
attr_accessible :expire_date, :start_date, :total_months

def total_months=(total)
  write_attribute :expire_date, start_date + 3.months
end
```

I'm getting a `nil` error because `start_date` returns nil. How can I get the start_date in date format?

Comment: Your method only overrides the set method for the `total_months` attribute, and you don't know whether that will be set before or after the `start_date` attribute is set (it may not happen in the order given in the view). Try doing the `write_attribute :expire_date, start_date + 3.months` in a `before_save` callback. Also, an aside, it looks like you're overriding your `total_months` attribute setter without setting `total_months`, so your `total_months` won't get set.

Comment: I took out part of the code that wasn't relevant to the problem (such as setting the total_months value in the setter function). You led me in the right direction though! Having a before_save callback was exactly the route I neededto take. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method only overrides the set method for the `total_months` attribute, and you don't know whether that will be set before or after the `start_date` attribute is set (it may not happen in the order given in the view). Try doing the `write_attribute :expire_date, start_date + 3.months` in a `before_save` callback.

So something like:

```
before_save :do_before_save

def do_before_save
  self.expire_date = start_date + 3.months if start_date
end
```